# Ошибка в Pycharm: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pycharm, chromedriver

Я новичок в автоматизации и пытаюсь написать обычный тест на авторизацию в Pycharm на Python, но, когда дело доходит до нажатия на строки ввода путем click() на самих сайтах или до самого ввода данных sendkeys(""), ничего не работает, выдает мне сообщение об ошибке (пробовала Expected Conditions, добавление User Agent, waits и разные пути для нахождения элемента),что я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста!:( текст ошибки + сам код:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[class*=VkIdForm__input]"}
(Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.103)


Process finished with exit code 1



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
link = "https://www.google.ru/"
driver.get(link)

search_string = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_string.send_keys("В контакте")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "gNO89b").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "LC20lb").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class*=VkIdForm__input]").click()
```

Comment: Всё так. Видимо у вас  vk открывается в новой вкладке, а селениум остается в текущей вкладке.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, это можно как то пофиксить?

Comment: 1) можно переключиться на вкладку 2) можно полазить в конфиге браузера (для хрома не знаю) 3) внезапно, google.com этим не страдает.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, driver.switch_to.window мне помог! Но только теперь не отправить значение в поле, пишет : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendkeys' :D